# How to put changing image on top of static image? "img ID" breaks image position, "img class" breaks image change function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a basic replica HTML gadget that replicates a car radio. Right now, I'm trying to make a changing image on top of my static image. All works fine until I route it to my function.

The below code works with the function just fine, and the image changes, but the image just goes to 0px 0px on top of the image instead of 145x62 inwards:

```
<img id="theImage" src="images/First.png">
```

As soon as I change "img id=" to "img class=" the image goes exactly where I want it to ontop of my other image, but the function breaks and nothing changes when I click the "101.1" button.

I've tried using getElementsByClassName but that didn't work either. Am currently at a wall and can't find a solution.

```
<script src="pause.js"></script>
<script>
function play(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("ONE");
   ONE.play();
   document.getElementById("theImage").src="images/KOSI.png";
   document.getElementById('chgID').innerHTML='KOSI-FM';
   document.getElementById('chgF').innerHTML='101.1';
   document.getElementById('chgCty').innerHTML='Denver, CO';
   document.getElementById('chgInf').innerHTML='KOSI 101.1';
             }
function playTwo(){
   var audioTwo = document.getElementById("TWO");
   TWO.play();
   document.getElementById("theImage").src="images/KRPX.png";
   document.getElementById('chgID').innerHTML='KRPX-FM';
   document.getElementById('chgF').innerHTML='95.3';
   document.getElementById('chgCty').innerHTML='Wellington, UT';
             }

</script>
<audio id="ONE" src="http://live.audio/live" preload="none"></audio>
<audio id="TWO" src="http://live.audio/live" preload="none"></audio>

<img src="main.png" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
  <area title="ONE" coords="8,328,279,405" shape="rect" onclick="play()">
  <area title="TWO" coords="286,326,561,417" shape="rect" onclick="playTwo()">
  <area title="THREE" coords="568,328,840,416" shape="rect">
  <area title="FOUR" coords="5,417,279,501" shape="rect">
  <area title="FIVE" coords="286,417,561,496" shape="rect">
  <area title="SIX" coords="564,418,838,493" shape="rect">  
</map>


<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<table align="right">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Station ID:</td>
    <td><div id="chgID">XXXX-FM</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Freq.:</td>
    <td><div id="chgF">00.0</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>City:</td>
    <td><div id="chgCty">City, ST</div></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Info:</td>
    <td><div id="chgInf"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<style>
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.theImage {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 145px;
  right: 62px;
}
</style>
<img class="theImage" src="images/First.png">
```

Comment: First, what happens if you change `.theImage` to `#theImage` in your `<style>` tag, and revert back to `id="theImage"` on the element?

Comment: It would help if you supplied a working example :)

Comment: Ashton, That did the trick exactly! Can't believe such a simple change had me so stuck. Thank you so much!